# How can I execute SQL scripts using TeamCity?

Tags: sql, command-line, scripting, continuous-integration, teamcity

I´m new with **TeamCity** and I don´t know how to run `SQL scripts` with it.

Is the way simply selecting the path of those scripts in a **Command Line Build Runner** ?

I´m pretty lost.

Regards.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In a command line build step:

*Command executable*: `c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\sqlcmd.exe`
*Command parameters*: `-S <server> -i <path_to_file>` ***<== Note: that's a capital `-S`!***

You may need to change the `100` to something else, depending on the version of the SQL Server tools that you have installed on the build agent.

Comment: This has now tripped up multiple people I know, so I'll post it here for next time somebody I know googles it then comes to ask me what's wrong: That `-S` is a *CAPITAL* `S` :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe that SQLCMD / SQLPLUS / MYSQL are available as standalone executables which you can install on the TeamCity server.

[Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 R2 Feature Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16978)

[Oracle SQL Plus](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html)

[MYSQL Command Line](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql.html)

However, without knowing your actual SQL Platform this may differ and the provider should have an alternative.

You can then create a Command Line Runner to call the executeable and pass in the parameters required, which are further explained here.

[Using the sqlcmd Utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165702%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

[Using sqlplus utility](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/e10320/sqlplus.htm)

If you are looking at doing Database Migrations as part of your CI process, it would also be worth checking out [RoundhousE](https://github.com/chucknorris/roundhouse)